# Java JNI Create header file with CMD javac -h

Tags: java, java-native-interface

When I'm trying to create the header file using javac -h from CMD, I get `error: file not found: Launcher.java`. What do I need to change in the following command to make it work? I do need to use CMD because this will be integrated in another program for use with jpackage, to run these commands automatically from there.

```
javac -h "Location where to save the created header file" ClassWithJNIFunction.java -cp "Location of bin folder from Project\bin" -d "Where to place class files created" -encoding utf8 --module-path "Path to folder\javafx-jmods-16" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.base
```

Practical example:

```
javac -h "E:\JNI\_JavaHeaders" Launcher.java -cp "E:\Java\Auto Key Press\bin" -d "E:\JNI\_JavaHeaders\ClassFiles" -encoding utf8 --module-path "D:\Java\javafx-jmods-16" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.graphics,javafx.fxml,javafx.base
```

Solution thanks to Botje:

When running javac, make sure that CMD directory is the same one as where your java file is located. One way to do this is using File Explorer, go to the location java file is in, hold SHIFT key then right click in that folder, and you should see an option "Open PowerShell window here", for Windows 10 users.

Comment: Are you currently in the directory that contains Launcher.java?

Comment: You are right, that was the problem. It's been like over 8 month since I last had to create  header file, and I'm not usually using JNI, in my notes I forgat to add that simple observation, to have CMD in the same location with the java file. I though maybe they changed something, because that first form used to work, silly me. :)
Thank you!